# TypeError: signup is not a function while try to signup using formik and yup in MERN

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern, formik, yup

I'm working on a social media app with MERN stack.
I've tested backend with postman and everything was ok, signup and signin works properly in postman, but with frontend running when I'm trying to send a request in the browser for signup, I've got this error

```
Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() TypeError: signup is not a function
    at onSubmit (main.5bed0d215acd146d9ef1.hot-update.js:35:11)
    at Formik.tsx:859:1
    at Formik.tsx:1213:1
    at Formik.tsx:766:1
(anonymous) @ Formik.tsx:834
Promise.catch (async)
(anonymous) @ Formik.tsx:833
(anonymous) @ Formik.tsx:1213
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
```

here is SignupForm.js

```
import { useSignup } from "../hooks/useSignup.js";
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import { UserSignupValidation } from '../validation/yupUserSchema.js';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";



const SignupForm = () => {
  
  const { signup } = useSignup();
  const onSubmit = async (values, actions) => {
    await signup(values);
    actions.resetForm();
  };
  
  const { values, errors, touched, isSubmitting, handleSubmit, handleBlur, handleChange } = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      passwordConfirmation: '',
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      birthDate: '',
      phoneNumber: ''
    },
    validationSchema: UserSignupValidation,
    onSubmit
  });


  if (!isSubmitting) {
    return (
    <div className="signup-input">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input
          id="firstName"
          type="text"
          placeholder="first name"
          value={values.firstName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          className={errors.firstName && touched.firstName ? 'input-error' : ''}
          
        />
          {errors.email && touched.email && <p className="error">{errors.email}</p>}
          
        <label htmlFor="lastName">last name</label>
        <input
          id="lastName"
          type="lastName"
          placeholder="lastName"
          value={values.lastName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          className={errors.lastName && touched.lastName ? 'input-error' : ''}
        />
          {errors.email && touched.email && <p className="error">{errors.email}</p>}
          
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input
          id="email"
          type="email"
          placeholder="email"
          value={values.email}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          className={errors.email && touched.email ? 'input-error' : ''}
        />
          {errors.email && touched.email && <p className="error">{errors.email}</p>}
          
        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
        <input
          id="password"
          type="password"
          placeholder="password"
          value={values.password}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          className={errors.password && touched.password ? 'input-error' : ''}
        />
          {errors.password && touched.password && <p className="error">{errors.password}</p>}

        <label htmlFor="passwordConfirmation">confirm password</label>
        <input
          id="passwordConfirmation"
          type="password"
          placeholder="passwordConfirmation"
          value={values.passwordConfirmation}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          className={errors.passwordConfirmation && touched.passwordConfirmation ? 'input-error' : ''}
        />
          {errors.passwordConfirmation && touched.passwordConfirmation && <p className="error">{errors.passwordConfirmation}</p>}
          
        <label htmlFor="birthDate">date of birth</label>
        <input
          id="birthDate"
          type="date"
          placeholder="birthDate"
          value={values.birthDate}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          className={errors.birthDate && touched.birthDate ? 'input-error' : ''}
        />
          {errors.birthDate && touched.birthDate && <p className="error">{errors.birthDate}</p>}
          
        <label htmlFor="phoneNumber">phone number</label>
        <input
          id="phoneNumber"
          type="tel"
          placeholder="phoneNumber"
          value={values.phoneNumber}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          className={errors.phoneNumber && touched.phoneNumber ? 'input-error' : ''}
        />
          {errors.phoneNumber && touched.phoneNumber && <p className="error">{errors.phoneNumber}</p>}
          
        <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
      </form>
      <Link to={'/user/auth/login'}>Allready have an account? Sign in here!</Link>  
    </div>
  );
  }

  if (isSubmitting) {
    return (
      <div className="loading">
        <h1>Signing Up</h1>
        
      </div>
    )
  }
}
 
export default SignupForm;
```

Here is useSignup.js hook

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from '../contexts/AuthContext.js';

export const useSignup = async () => {

  const { dispatch } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const signup = async (email, password) => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/user/auth/signup', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password })
    })

    const json = await response.json()

    if (!response.ok) {
    }
    if (response.ok) {
      //save the user to local storage
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(json));

      //update the auth context
      dispatch({
        type: 'LOGIN',
        payload: json
      })
    }
  }

  return { signup };
};
```

Here is AuthContext.js that I wrap my APP in index.js with it

```
import { useEffect, useReducer, createContext } from 'react';

const initialState = { state: null };
export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const authReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN':
      return { user: action.payload }
    case 'LOGOUT':
      return { user: null }
    default:
      return state
  };
};

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    if (user) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'LOGIN',
        payload: user
      })
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      { children }
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
};
```

the funnier thing is that everything in signin is same but I got absolutely nothing!!

LoginForm.js :

```
import { useLogin } from "../hooks/useLogin";
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import { UserSigninValidation } from '../validation/yupUserSchema.js';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";



const LoginForm = () => {
  const { login } = useLogin();

  const onSubmit = async (values, actions) => {
    await login(values);
    actions.resetForm();
  };
  const { values, errors, touched, isSubmitting, handleSubmit, handleBlur, handleChange } = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    },
    validationSchema: UserSigninValidation,
    onSubmit
  });


  if (!isSubmitting) {
    return (
    <div className="signin-input">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input
          id="email"
          type="email"
          placeholder="email"
          value={values.email}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          className={errors.email && touched.email ? 'input-error' : ''}
        />
          {errors.email && touched.email && <p className="error">{errors.email}</p>}
          
        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
        <input
          id="password"
          type="password"
          placeholder="password"
          value={values.password}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          className={errors.password && touched.password ? 'input-error' : ''}
        />
          {errors.password && touched.password && <p className="error">{errors.password}</p>}
          
        <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
        <Link to={'/user/auth/signup'}>Don't have an account? Signup here!</Link>  
      </form>
    </div>
  );
  }

  if (isSubmitting) {
    return (
      <div className="loading">
        <h1>Signing In</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
 
export default LoginForm;
```

useLogin.js hook

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from '../contexts/AuthContext.js';

export const useLogin = () => {
  const { dispatch } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const login = async (email, password) => {
    const response = await fetch('/user/auth/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password })
    })
    const json = await response.json();

    if (response.ok) {
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(json));

      dispatch({
        type: 'LOGIN',
        payload: json
      });

    }
  }
  return { login };
};
```

AND here is some backend files

userAuth controller:

```
import UserModel from '../models/UserModel.js';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import yup from 'yup';

dotenv.config();
const passRule = process.env.PASSWORD_RULE;
const secretKey = process.env.SEC_KEY;
const createToken = function (_id) {
  return jwt.sign({ _id }, secretKey, { expiresIn: '1d' })
};

const yupUserSchema = yup.object().shape({
  firstName: yup.string().min(2).max(10).required('First name is required.'),
  lastName: yup.string().max(15).required('Last name is required.'),
  email: yup.string().email('Enter a valid email address.').required('Email is required.'),
  password: yup.string().min(5).matches(passRule, { message: "Please enter a stronger password" }).required("Password required"),
  friends: yup.array(),
  birthDate: yup.date().required('Birthday is required.'),
  picture: yup.string(),
  phoneNumber: yup.string().required('Phone number is required.'),
  city: yup.string(),
  status: yup.boolean(),
  occupation: yup.string(),
  education: yup.string(),
  location: yup.string(),
  bio: yup.string(),
  gender: yup.string()
})

export const signupUser = async (req, res) => {
  const {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    password,
    friends,
    birthDate,
    picture,
    phoneNumber,
    city,
    status,
    occupation,
    education,
    location,
    bio,
    gender
  } = req.body;

  const isValid = await yupUserSchema.isValid({
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    password,
    friends,
    birthDate,
    picture,
    phoneNumber,
    city,
    status,
    occupation,
    education,
    location,
    bio,
    gender
  });
  
  try {
    const emailexists = await UserModel.findOne({ email });
    if (emailexists) return res.status(400).json({error: 'Email is already in use.'})
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    const newUser = await UserModel.create({
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      password: hashedPassword,
      friends,
      birthDate,
      picture,
      phoneNumber,
      city,
      status,
      occupation,
      education,
      location,
      bio,
      gender
    })
    const token = createToken(newUser._id);
    console.log(newUser);
    res.status(201).json({ newUser, token });

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message })
  }
};

export const signinUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email });
    const token = createToken(user._id);
    if (!user) return res.status(400).json({ error: "User does not exist. " });
    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid credentials. " });
    res.status(200).json({ user, token });

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
  };
};
```

user controller

```
import UserModel from '../models/UserModel.js';


/* GET USER */
export const getUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const id = req.params;
    const user = await UserModel.findById(id);
    res.status(200).json(user);

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
  };
};

/* GET USER'S FRIENDS */
export const getUserFriends = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const user = await UserModel.findById(id);

    const friends = await Promise.all(
      user.friends.map((id) => UserModel.findById(id))
    );
    const formattedFriends = friends.map(
      ({ _id, firstName, lastName, occupation, location, picture, birthDate, city, status, bio }) => {
        return { _id, firstName, lastName, occupation, location, picture, birthDate, city, status, bio };
      }
    );
    res.status(200).json(formattedFriends);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};


/* UPDATE A USER */
export const editUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const userToUpdate = await UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { ...req.body });
    res.status(200).json(userToUpdate);

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};

/* DELETE A USER */
export const deleteUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const userTodelete = await UserModel.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    res.status(200).json(userTodelete);

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};

/* ADD OR REMOVE A FRIEND */
export const addRemoveFriend = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id, friendId } = req.params;
    const user = await UserModel.findById(id);
    const friend = await UserModel.findById(friendId);

    if (user.friends.includes(friendId)) {
      user.friends = user.friends.filter((id) => id !== friendId);
      friend.friends = friend.friends.filter((id) => id !== id);
    } else {
      user.friends.push(friendId);
      friend.friends.push(id);
    }
    await user.save();
    await friend.save();

    const friends = await Promise.all(
      user.friends.map((id) => UserModel.findById(id))
    );
    const formattedFriends = friends.map(
      ({ _id, firstName, lastName, occupation, location, picturePath, birthDate, city, status, bio }) => {
        return { _id, firstName, lastName, occupation, location, picture, birthDate, city, status, bio };
      }
    );

    res.status(200).json(formattedFriends);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

verification middleware

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const secretKey = process.env.SEC_KEY;

export const verifyToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let token = req.header("Authorization");

    if (!token) {
      return res.status(403).send("Access Denied");
    }

    if (token.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
      token = token.slice(7, token.length).trimLeft();
    }

    const verified = jwt.verify(token, secretKey);
    req.user = verified;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
};
```

and routes

```
import express from 'express';
import { getUser, getUserFriends, editUser, deleteUser, addRemoveFriend } from '../controllers/userController.js';
import { verifyToken } from '../middlewares/verification.js';
import { signinUser, signupUser } from "../controllers/userAuth.js";


const router = express.Router();

router.get('/:id', verifyToken, getUser);
router.get('/:id/friends', verifyToken, getUserFriends);

router.patch('/:id', verifyToken, editUser);
router.patch('/:id/:friendId', verifyToken, addRemoveFriend);

router.delete('/:id', verifyToken, deleteUser);

router.post('/auth/login', verifyToken, signinUser);
router.post('/auth/signup', signupUser);

export default router;
```

and user MODEL for further needs!!

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String, required: true,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String, required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String, required: true, unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String, required: true,
  },
  friends: {
    type: Array, default: [],
  },
  birthDate: {
    type: Date,
  },
  picture: {
    type: String, default: ''
  },
  phoneNumber: String,
  city: String,
  status: Boolean,
  occupation: String,
  education: String,
  location: String,
  bio: String,
  gender: String
});

const UserModel = mongoose.model('UserModel', userSchema);
export default UserModel;
```

At first I had a problem with proxy and fetch (the proxy in package.json didn't proxy the fetch address to backend server and I removed it and used cors instead)
then this happened! nore signup neither signin work properly